# Log analytics query for Monitoring external IP

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I need to monitor an external IP. This is for the Virtual Network Gateway, I cant use AzureDiagnostics because we are using Policy based tunnel.

Anyone with an idéa for monitoring this external IP? And get it in Log analytics for monitoring?

Comment: What is `an external IP`?Is it the VPN gateway public IP address?

Comment: Hi, exactly. I got an IP for the tunnel that is allowed to ping.

Answer (score 0):

Azure supports metric [Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftnetworkpublicipaddresses) type in Azure Monitor. You could use [metrics explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-charts) to analyze collected metrics on a chart and compare metrics from different resources. You can also retrieve metrics by using the [Azure monitoring REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/rest-api-walkthrough). Moreover, for non-VM resources, you need to configure diagnostic settings to send logs for log analytics.

[image]